# angular.js:4630 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been combing through internet for solution of this error.I cant seem to find any error with the code. HELP!
I am following microsoft jumpstart tutorial for mean stack, I have pretty much the same code but theirs is running fine.
[I cant understand why the angular code is getting displayed on the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBvfd.png)

```html
angular.js:4630 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=chirpApp&p1=Error%3…oogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)
```

```js
var app = angular.module('chirpApp', []);
app.controller('maincontroller', function($scope) {
      $scope.posts = [];
      $scope.newPosts = {
        created_by: '',
        text = '',
        create_at: ''
      };
      $scope.post = function() {
        $scope.newPosts.create_at = Date.now();
        $scope.posts.push($scope.newPosts);
        $scope.newPosts = {
          created_by: '',
          text = '',
          create_at = ''
        };

      }



    };
```

```html
<!--main.html-->
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Chirp</title>
  <script source="js/chirpApp.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
</head>

<body ng-app="chirpApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <div id='main'>
    <form ng-submit="post()">
      <input required type="text" placeholder="Your name" ng-model="newPosts.created_by" />
      <textarea required maxlength="200" rows="3" placeholder="Say something" ng-model="newPosts.text"></textarea>
      <input class="button" type="submit" value="Chirp!" />
    </form>
    <div id="post-stream">
      <h4>Chirp Feed</h4>
      <div class='post' ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'create_at': true" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
        <p>{{post.created_by}} says {{post.text}} at {{post.create_at}}</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[NEW SITUATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phxEn.png)

Answer (score 2):

There are few issues in your code.

1. `text` is a key to object $scope.newPosts, So you have to replace `=`  with `:`

Modify code in both the places `$scope.newPosts`

```
 $scope.newPosts = {
            created_by: '',
            text : '',
            create_at: ''
          };
```

2. External scripts are loaded using [**src**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) attribute but you are using source, so chirpApp is not at all loading in page

Please correctly refer file location while working in local machine. Also order of file is important, as pointed out by Venkant

You check this [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/7gQorvK4OdNlE6uDetwA?p=preview)

Comment: I've removed all the typos and bugs you've mentioned , my code is very similar to the one on PLUNKER but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: did you also changed the controller name & order of loading files as suggested in another answers?  Beside also check if you js files is loading properly. If you are using chrome open developers tool go to network tab, refresh the page. If file is not correctly loading it will be highlighted in red

Comment: I did change the controller name, and the order has been rectified too. The js files are loading alright, no file highlighted on network tab. Can't seem to figure out the problem.

Comment: repost your code and also snapshot of what you are seeing in network tab and console tab

Comment: link for code- https://plnkr.co/edit/5fmAPbJzfogROpOw1wC5?p=preview I have posted the snaps for the webpage too.

Comment: ng-app need to be added in html  tag and while working on plunker there is no need of putting js before file name. The are on same level. Please again refer to my plunker & please check where ng-app is added and how chirpApp.js is included in page

Comment: ive added js before the file because the files are not on the same level on my PC and the ng-app is added in the html tag https://plnkr.co/edit/5fmAPbJzfogROpOw1wC5?p=preview . Its working on plunker but not on my PC

Comment: then your files are not loading . Please search how to add external js file in html page

Answer (score 0):

`angular.min.js` should be loaded before `chirpApp.js`. So, put the

```
 <script source="js/chirpApp.js"></script>
```

line after the

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

line.

Comment: In addition need to pass $scope & other dependencies as string before injecting them  ('maincontroller', ['$scope',function($scope) {..}])

Comment: getting angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]. I have already tried doing that, no luck

Comment: @user2181397 Im a bit new to angualrjs , care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

The capitalization of `mainController` doesn't match between HTML and JS.

JS

```
app.controller('maincontroller', function($scope) {
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="chirpApp" ng-controller="mainController">
```